# Compile Fortran Function using gfortran: object file was built for newer macOS version than being linked

Tags: macos, gfortran, fortran95

Given a very simple fortran (95) function and a very simple c++ call to the program, I should be able to compile the program using:

```
g++ -c main1.cpp
gfortran -c test.f95
g++ main1.o test.o -o run
```

However, here I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: object file (test.o) was built for newer macOS version (11.5) than being linked (11.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "hello_()", referenced from:
      _main in main1.o
 "__gfortran_st_write", referenced from:
      _hello_ in test.o
  "__gfortran_st_write_done", referenced from:
  _hello_ in test.o
```

"__gfortran_transfer_character_write", referenced from:
*hello* in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here, adding a `-v` tag before the `-o` tag and after the `-o` tag and the exe run did   not solve the problem, as suggested by the error message.

Comment: Please include your code as a [mre].

Comment: "Use -v to see invocation" does *not* mean "use -v to solve the problem". You have an incorrect version of gfortran installed.

Comment: You need to explicitly link in the gfortran runtime library.